# Parsing primitive types in Circe

Tags: json, scala, parsing, circe

I'm having an issue with json parsing when field can have different primitive value types. For example, I can get json:

```
{
  "name" : "john",
  "age" : 31
}
```

Or it can be in this form:

```
{
  "name" : "john",
  "age" : "thirty one"
}
```

Or in this way:

```
{
  "name" : "john",
  "age" : 31.0
}
```

I want to be able to parse field `age` to the following ADTs instances:

```
sealed trait PrimitiveWrapper

case class IntWrapper(v: Int) extends PrimitiveWrapper

case class StringWrapper(v: String) extends PrimitiveWrapper

case class FloatWrapper(v: Float) extends PrimitiveWrapper
```

So at the end I can get something like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: PrimitiveWrapper)
```

How can I do this? I found this topic: [How to decode an ADT with circe without disambiguating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165460/how-to-decode-an-adt-with-circe-without-disambiguating-objects)

But in that solution we are parsing not primitive fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do:

```scala
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.Decoder, io.circe.generic.auto._

sealed trait PrimitiveWrapper

case class IntWrapper(v: Int) extends PrimitiveWrapper

case class StringWrapper(v: String) extends PrimitiveWrapper

case class FloatWrapper(v: Float) extends PrimitiveWrapper

case class Person(name: String, age: PrimitiveWrapper)

object GenericDerivation {

  implicit val decodePrimitiveWrapper: Decoder[PrimitiveWrapper] =
    List[Decoder[PrimitiveWrapper]](
      Decoder.decodeInt.map(IntWrapper).widen,
      Decoder.decodeString.map(StringWrapper).widen,
      Decoder.decodeFloat.map(FloatWrapper).widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import io.circe.parser.decode
    println(decode[Person]("""{"name" : "john", "age" : 31 }"""))
    println(decode[Person]("""{"name" : "john", "age" : "thirty one" }"""))
    println(decode[Person]("""{"name" : "john", "age" : 31.3 }"""))
    // Prints
    // Right(Person(john,IntWrapper(31)))
    // Right(Person(john,StringWrapper(thirty one)))
    // Right(Person(john,FloatWrapper(31.3)))
  }
}
```

**Note:**  The following get parse using an `IntWrapper`

```scala
 println(decode[Person]("""{"name" : "john", "age" : 31.0 }"""))
```

**Update:** As @Travis pointed out the `decodePrimitiveWrapper` can be written like this:

```scala
  implicit val decodePrimitiveWrapper: Decoder[PrimitiveWrapper] =
      Decoder.decodeInt.map(IntWrapper).widen[PrimitiveWrapper] or
        Decoder.decodeString.map(StringWrapper).widen[PrimitiveWrapper] or
        Decoder.decodeFloat.map(FloatWrapper).widen[PrimitiveWrapper]
```

Comment: I'd write out the two `or`s instead of reducing but otherwise this is what I'd do.